# Limit cpu usage on multiple PHP script running asyncronously

Tags: php, bash, command-line-interface, cron-task

I'm running a PHP code via CLI by setting a cron-job. The script reads about 10000 records from database and runs 10000 new scripts (by `exec` command) without waiting for previous script to be done. I use this because I want all those tasks run fast. (each one takes about 10 seconds).
When number of tasks that are running gets large, CPU usage become 100% and can't work with server (CentOS). How can I handle this?

Comment: You have to increase RAM size

Comment: 1) Do not run 10000 new scripts, it's not smart at all, you don't have 10000 CPU cores. 2) Identify why your tasks are slow - increasing number of scripts doesn't make them faster. If you are writing to the database, spawning 10k scripts won't make it run faster. You're going about this the wrong way completely.

Comment: @Mjh Thank you. Each script is executing an curl command to an external url and waits for response and then writes them into database. I need answer of each request. I'm just trying to check [gearman](http://gearman.org/). I have a future decision to use nodejs to handle this by queues.

Comment: Can't you use Guzzle to perform asynchronous http requests and then in the promise function perform the task of writing to the db?

Comment: Better if you could batch processing this but there other alternatives as command ``nice``. You can set priority to scripts

Answer (score 2):

You need to limit the number of scripts running in parallel at any given time because running 10,000 concurrent scripts is clearly saturating your system.  Instead, you should queue up each task and process 25 or 50 (whatever causes a reasonable amount of load) tasks at the same time.

Without much knowledge of how these scripts actually work, I can't really give you much advice code-wise, but you definitely need to have a queue in place to limit the number of concurrent instances of your script running at the same time.

Also check out semaphores, they might be useful for this producer/consumer model

Comment: Thank you @edhurtig. I tried to limit number of asynchronous calls. But the problem is this that if i run 10000 script together CPU usage gets 100% for about 10 minutes (for example) and if i run 25 script at one CPU usage gets 100% for about 10 seconds. And the problem still exists.

Comment: Then you probably need to use a multi core processor and set a CPU afinity to the upper half of the cores (or something like that).  You can also set the process priority to be very low.  Your CPU will still max out, but the process scheduler will take these scoots off the CPU when you do other things

Comment: I would also agree with @mjh, if all these scripts are going is a curl, then I would recommend using Guzzle or some other a sync http request technology.  You still might end up with a high CPU load, if so then my comment about the CPU affinity and process priority should help

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a script that handle parallel execution of commands. It basically allows the operator to tune the number of concurrent processes at runtime.
If you feel that CPU usage is too high, just decrease the value in /etc/maxprunning

```
CMD="path-of-your-php-script"


function getMaxPRunning {
    cat /etc/maxprunning
}

function limitProcs {
    PRUNNING=`ps auxw | grep -v grep | grep "$CMD" | wc -l`
    #echo "Now running $PRUNNING processes, MAX:$MAXPRUNNING"
    [ $PRUNNING -ge $MAXPRUNNING ] && {
       sleep 1
       return
    }
    #echo "Launching new process"
    sleep 0.2
    $CMD &
}

MAXPRUNNING=`getMaxPRunning`
C=1
while [ 1 ];do
   MAXPRUNNING=`getMaxPRunning`
   limitProcs
done
```

If you want your php scripts to ignore an accidental parent's death, put this line at the top of the php script

```
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
```